# Spring boot Rest API give empty data in browser

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

Ineed to help I have a spring boot project with h2 database. I added data in the data.sql but the data wasn't inserted into the database however tables are created successfully when I call the findAll API I get an empty data.

this is application.properties

```
server.port=8080
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:todo
spring.datasource.username=to
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
logging.level.org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate=DEBUG
logging.level.org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils=TRACE
```

this is todo.java

```
package todo.model;

import java.time.LocalDate;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "todo")
public class Todo {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String task;
    private LocalDate date;
    private boolean isDone;

}
```

this todo.repository

```
package todo.repositories;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import todo.model.Todo;

@Repository
public interface TodoRepository extends JpaRepository<Todo, Integer> {

}
```

this is todo.controller

```
package todo.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import todo.model.Todo;
import todo.repositories.TodoRepository;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/todo")
public class TodoController {

    @Autowired
    TodoRepository todoRepository;

    @GetMapping("/findall")
    public List<Todo> fetchAll() {

        return this.todoRepository.findAll();

    }

    @PostMapping("/add")
    public ResponseEntity<?> addTodo(@RequestBody Todo todo) {

        return new ResponseEntity<>(this.todoRepository.save(todo), HttpStatus.CREATED);

    }
}
```

this is data.sql

```
INSERT INTO todo (task,date,is_done) VALUES ('sleep','200-12-05',false);
INSERT INTO todo (task,date,is_done) VALUES ('down','2001-12-05',true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Set in application.properties the path to the data file:

```
spring.datasource.platform=h2
spring.datasource.schema=classpath:/h2/schema-h2.sql
spring.datasource.data=classpath:/h2/data-h2.sql
```

The data file is located in the resources/h2 directory with the name data-h2.sql for this example.

Comment: Not work for me  get an empty data in browser

Comment: And if you use the h2-console? Can you see the data? http://localhost:8080/h2-console

Comment: Set for the h2-console in application.properites: spring.h2.console.enabled=true 
spring.h2.console.path=/console

Comment: I find data in h2 console but in browser data get empty

Comment: Very good. Then the problem is not the loading of the data. One more small note: I find date as a name for the database field a bit unfortunate. date could be a keyword, maybe not in h2, but in another database.

Comment: but when i send data from postman in h2 console, i find the data i transferred is null

Comment: And when you make a GET request with Postman, you don't see any data either? Basically, everything looks good.

Comment: Tricky. I'm afraid I can't help you here. But good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much finally I changed eclipse editor and I used intileji it work